# Kubernetes deployment read-only filesystem error

Tags: docker, sed, deployment, kubernetes, airflow

I am facing an error while deploying Airflow on Kubernetes (precisely this version of Airflow https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/1.8.1/Dockerfile) regarding writing permissions onto the filesystem.

The error displayed on the logs of the pod is:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/local/airflow/sed18bPUH: Read-only file system
sed: -e expression #1, char 131: unterminated `s' command
sed: -e expression #1, char 118: unterminated `s' command
Initialize database...
sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/local/airflow/sedouxZBL: Read-only file system
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 769, in
    ....
    with open(TEST_CONFIG_FILE, 'w') as f:
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/usr/local/airflow/unittests.cfg'
```

It seems that the filesystem is read-only but I do not understand why it is. I am not sure if it is a **Kubernetes misconfiguration** (do I need a special RBAC for pods ? No idea) or if it is a problem with the **Dockerfile**.

The deployment file looks like the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: airflow
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: webserver
        image: davideberdin/docker-airflow:0.0.4
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 50m
            memory: 128Mi
        securityContext:  #does not have any effect
          runAsUser: 0    #does not have any effect
        ports:
        - name: airflow-web
          containerPort: 8080
        args: ["webserver"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: airflow-config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
            readOnly: false #does not have any effect
          - name: airflow-logs
            mountPath: /usr/local/logs
            readOnly: false #does not have any effect
      volumes:
      - name: airflow-config-volume
        secret:
          secretName: airflow-config-secret
      - name: airflow-parameters-volume
        secret:
          secretName: airflow-parameters-secret
      - name: airflow-logs
        emptyDir: {}
```

Any idea how I can make the filesystem writable? The container is running as **USER airflow** but I think that this user has root privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: airflow-config-volume
        mountPath: /usr/local/airflow
  volumes:
  - name: airflow-config-volume
    secret:
      secretName: airflow-config-secret
```

Is the source of your problems, for two reasons: first, you have smashed the airflow user's [home directory](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/1.8.1/Dockerfile#L51) by volume mounting your secret onto the image directly into a place where the image expects [a directory owned by `airflow`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/1.8.1/Dockerfile#L73).

Separately, while I would have to fire up a cluster to confirm 100%, I am pretty sure that `Secret` volume mounts -- and I *think* their `ConfigMap` friends -- are read-only projections into the Pod filesystems; that suspicion certainly appears to match your experience. There is certainly no expectation that changes to those volumes propagate back up into the kubernetes cluster, so why pretend otherwise.

If you want to continue to attempt such a thing, you do actually have influence over the [`defaultMode`](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#secretvolumesource-v1-core) of the *files* projected into that `volumeMount`, so you could set them to `0666`, but caveat emptor for sure. The short version is, by far, not to smash `$AIRFLOW_HOME` with a volume mount.

Answer (score 44):

Since kubernetes version 1.9 and forth, volumeMounts behavior on secret, configMap, downwardAPI and projected have changed to Read-Only by default.

A workaround to the problem is to create an emtpyDir volume and copy the contents into it and execute/write whatever you need.

this is a small snippet to demonstrate.

```
    initContainers:
    - name: copy-ro-scripts
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c', 'cp /scripts/* /etc/pre-install/']
      volumeMounts:
        - name: scripts
          mountPath: /scripts
        - name: pre-install
          mountPath: /etc/pre-install
   volumes:
      - name: pre-install
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: scripts
        configMap:
          name: bla
```

Merged PR which causes this break :( 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/58720

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the Kubernetes change.  I'm working with Consul rather than Airflow but hit a similar problem.  Your answer has given me a lead in the right direction.

Comment: I'm happy I could help :P

Comment: I ran in the same problem and this helped me to solve it. Thanks @levich

Comment: for configMap mounted as volume, do add defaultMode: 0700 so that your scripts can be executed.

Comment: For a little bit bigger example showing initContainers in use with emptyDir, see this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container

Comment: yes i tried to mount config map and secret for ca certificate and seems there is no permission to add to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ location.  I think once image is loaded it becomes readonly