# Permission Denied error using kubernetes and Logstash

Tags: kubernetes, logstash

I am using a Logstash sidecar to monitor log files from a deployment. I Was intending to use a configmap to pass my own logstash.yml to the Logstash sidecar. My first implementation was as follows

```
  - name: logstash-sidecar
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.0
    volumeMounts:
      - name: shared-plugins-logstash
        mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/plugins/
      - name: logstash-yaml
        readOnly: true
        mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        subPath: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-conf
        mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
        subPath: logstash.conf
      - name: shared-logs
        mountpath: var/logs/logstash
```

with the volumes as follows

```
volumes:
  - name: shared-plugins-logstash
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: logstash-yaml
    configMap:
      name: logstash-yaml
  - name: logstash-conf
    configMap:
      name: logstash-conf
```

The logstash-yaml config map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-yaml
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
    log.level: debug
    path.logs: /var/logs/logstash
```

This would generate an error saying that /usr/share/logstash/config/ is a read-only file system

I researched the problem and also saw the following solution

[Kubernetes deployment read-only filesystem error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614034/kubernetes-deployment-read-only-filesystem-error)

The 2nd solution of this creates a new error saying that

permission denied cannot open /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml

setting the security context of the container as 2000 did not help in running the container as well.

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also tried default mode and such which also didn't work

Comment: Have you checked the permissions inside logstash container for this folder ( `/usr/share/logstash/config/`)?

Comment: The container often crashes before I can even see it. But i tried mounting the configmap volume onto a busybox container and it shows that it is owned by root. So I would assume that would still be the case in the logstash scenario

Comment: Can you share logstash sidecar deployment?

Comment: @RanikaNisal could you solve this problem ? thanks in advance